How to change navigation node url in SharePoint Online
We are trying to change some URLs of our hub navigation. Sometimes it is working fine but with some links we are not able to change the url. We have to delete them and create new ones. This is very frustrating. And yes I tried with a browser in incognito mode and to clear the cache and so on. The changes are just not saved.
So I tried to change the url via code. Thats not working too. Neither with classic csom nor with PnP Core.
PnP Core code:
node.Url = url;
await node.UpdateAsync();
await context.ExecuteAsync(); //This is not needed I guess, but tried it any way.

csom code looks almost the same:
node.Url = url;
node.Update();
await context.ExecuteQueryAsync();

Does anyone have a 100% working solution to change navigation nodes in SharePoint Online? This looks very buggy to me and is a big problem when working with the ootb navigation.

Try this(Site setting -> Navigation Settings) :

